# Dynamic Excel Hyperlink Excel 2003

Tags: hyperlink, excel-2003

I am attempting to have a hyperlink to:

-Sheet:  "Daily Trend" 
-Row:    65 
-column: column A + the number referenced in cell A2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
=HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(65,A2+1,,,"Daily Trend")))
```